# Angular 2 - How to access a variable in the callback and display it on the view

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue with my angular 2 code.

I want to display `this.restaurants` on my view after google request is handled.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private ps: PlacesService){
}

ngOnInit(){

if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {

        this.location.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.location.lng = position.coords.longitude;


        var request = {
            location: this.location,
            radius: '5000',
            types: ['restaurant']
        };

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: this.location,
          zoom: 15
        });

        this.service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);

        this.service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status, pagination) => {
            this.restaurants = results;
            console.log(this.restaurants); //logs an array
        });

        console.log(this.restaurants); //undefined

    });

}
```

}

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

<div id="map"></div>

<div>
    <app-search-results [restaurants]="restaurants"></app-search-results>
</div>
```

My loop in app-search-results component is not running because this.restaurants is undefined.

How could I access this variable when it's filled with results from the callback?

I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: Can you share the code for `app-search-results`? Where/how do you want to display this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `... // undefined` is executed before the response arrives. Only when the callback passed to `nearbySearch` is called, the data will be available. When you assign it to `this.restaurants` Angular change detection will update the binding. If it doesn't, then that's probably because `nearbySearch` does something fishy

You can try

```
constructor(private ps: PlacesService, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

...

    this.service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status, pagination) => {
        this.restaurants = results;
        console.log(this.restaurants); //logs an array
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        // or this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    });
```

Comment: Somehow `service.nearbySearch` breaks out of Angulars zone an Angular therefore doesn't get notified to run change detection. `detectChanges()` invokes it explicitely.